# How do I call a static function with model scopes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I wasn't sure how to get it to work syntax wise. I did get it to work like the following though:

```
  scope :out_of_stock, lambda{ |company| get_inventory(company, 'out_of_stock') }
  scope :in_stock, lambda{ |company| get_inventory(company, 'in_stock') }


  def self.get_inventory(company, stock_status)
    StockInventory.find_all_by_....
  end
```

However, is there a way to do it without the anonymous functions?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are no static functions in Ruby. The `self.get_inventory` is a class method, which is in effect a singleton instance method on the `Company` class. The `scope` call is itself a class method that dynamically defines other class methods, in this case `out_of_stock` and `in_stock`.

Second, it's hard to tell what you're trying to do, since you didn't include your entire method, but I'll assume you're trying to get the instances of `StockInventory` that have a particular company id and inventory status.

ActiveRecord allows you to use **finders**, as it appears you've done here, or **relations**, which are a bit more flexible, as they are typically chainable, and because their execution is delayed until absolutely necessary, meaning you can pass them around to different methods without hitting the database. Unless I'm looking up a single object with a known id, I usually stick to relations for this reason.

I'm going to make a few assumptions, since your question isn't particularly clear. If you have defined a relation between `Company` and `StockInventory` (like `has_many :stock_inventories` and `belongs_to :company`), you can use that relation as a starting point and defined a method like this on the `StockInventory` class:

```
def self.in_stock
  where(stock_status: "in stock") # or whatever
end
```

Note that instead of passing in a `Company` instance as an argument to a `Company` class method that ultimately loads some other class (this should be a red flag), you call this directly on the `StockInventory` class or any `StockInventory` relation. Plus, since it's a relation, you can chain other ActiveRecord methods to it, i.e. `my_company.stock_inventories.in_stock.limit(10)`.

You'll need to alter this method to fit your particular database columns and statuses, but this is as complicated as it needs to get.

Whatever the case, I recommend you read the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) guide - there's a lot you can do with it once you understand how it works.

Comment: One thing you missed is that those [horrific and nasty dynamic finder methods](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations) have been deprecated, replacing them with sensible `where` calls (as you've done) is the Right Thing to do.

Comment: Wow, nice to hear about the finders. To the future!